# Deleting messages in whatsapp with mobile data off

Tags: google-play-store

i sent a whatsapp message with my mobile data off. And then deleted it before turning on my mobile data. does this message get delivered?

Comment: This question is the same to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85752/message-sent-accidentally-in-whatspp/85866#85866)

Answer (score 0):

The message can be deleted based on the status that is shown in whatssapp.

1.That is there is clock symbol is shown it can be deleted safely (iff internet connection is off).

2.Otherwise that is a single tick mark is showing means it is now at whatsapp server so if you deleted or not it doesn't matter it will reach at the receiver whenever internet connection is available.