# Cancel sending a message to group in WhatsApp

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I mistakenly pasted a message in a WhatsApp group. I noticed that immediately and turned off my internet. The message was still not sent (single tick did not appear), and I deleted that message and turned on the internet.

Will this stop the message from getting sent to the group?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85752/will-whatsapp-deliver-a-message-that-was-accidentally-sent-while-data-was-off?rq=1 (based on self-experience at that time)

Answer (score 0):

The single tick means the message was sent to WhatsApp servers and, once it gets there, you can't cancel it.

Your only chance to cancel a message is when it still has a clock sign on the bubble -- meaning it didn't reach the servers yet. To do that, you press and hold the message and then delete it.